# Which is the more efficient way to swap these list elements in C#? Why do they behave differently?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, sorting, time-complexity

I'm doing brainteasers and exercises on hackerrank to prepare for an interview test and came across some weird behaviour.
The taks in question is Minimum Swaps 2 from the Interview Preparation Kit's Arrays section.

Depending on which of the two elements I put into my temporary variable, it either passes or fails on timeout on most test cases.

Version A:

```
static int minimumSwaps(int[] arr) {
    int swaps=0;
    int tmp=0;
    int n = arr.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i]==i+1) continue;

        tmp = arr[arr[i]-1]; 
        arr[arr[i]-1] = arr[i]; 
        arr[i] = tmp;
        
        i--;
        swaps++;
            
    }
    return swaps;
}
```

Version B

```
static int minimumSwaps(int[] arr) {
    int swaps=0;
    int tmp=0;
    int n = arr.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i]==i+1) continue;
        
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr[i]-1];
        arr[arr[i]-1]=tmp;
        
        i--;
        swaps++;
            
    }
    return swaps;
}
```

A passes, B times out on all but one test.

What it actually does is find the minimum amount of swaps to sort an array of consecutive integers. That's why i can be used to compare values and indices.
If arr[i] is on the corresponding index, we continue, if it's wrong, we swap it with the index it's supposed to be at, decrement i and repeat.

I'm honestly at a loss as to why storing arr[arr[i]-1] in tmp is less complicated than storing arr[i] first. It must have something to do with the intermediate machine code it get's compiled to, right?
I'd be grateful for any explanation so I don't run into similar issues in the future.

Comment: @juharr I feel beyond stupid now. At least a whole bunch of other programmers I asked were just as stumped. And no we're all not beginners lmao. Post it as a full response and I'll flag it as the answer.

Comment: For your interviews, you'll get higher credit by implementing a `Swap(a, b)` function.
It also gives you an opportunity to defer the `Swap` actual implementation towards the end of the interview, because it's pretty basic.
Remember, it's not all about **just** solving the problem.

Comment: Version B is bound to raise `IndexOutOfRangeException` unless all array int values are smaller than/equal to arr.Length and greater than -1.
Is the task to implement an array sort algorithm with minimal swap count, or what's the actual purpose?

Comment: @RudolfJan It's just a code challenge. Yes, putting the swap functionality in a dedicated method makes more sense. And that's what I'd do too. This was just a technical question about why one variant fails and not the other.  
We figured that one out. This is not production code, or anything of value beyond completing a challenge.